# Klein-Gordon equation for Schwarzschild

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I have seen in many texts that the form of the solution to the Klein-Gordon equation for Schwarzschild metric is:

$\phi(r,t,θ,φ)=r^{−1}f(r,t)Y_{lm}(θ,φ)$

where does the term $1/r$ comes from? I can see that the solution goes to zero at infinity and diverge at zero (which is not good)

Edit: I attach the reference where they have used it, Eq. 14.3.1
https://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/science_and_technology/physics/General_Relativity_Theory/General%20Relativity%20-%20R.%20Wald.pdf

Comment: (1) Nothing forbids your $f(r, t)$ to be $\propto r$ as $r \to 0$, which would counter the divergence. (2) $1/r$ divergence is not a problem per se as long as the volume of ${ r = R }$ vanishes fast enought (at least $\propto r^2$). (3) I guess the term comes from analyzing the asymptotic behaviour as $r \to 0$ but I am not sure (and therefore can't answer the question).

Comment: It would be useful to provide an example of a reference writing this down. Context might help notice why it is useful to factor out the $1/r$ factor

Answer (score 4):

This is just the form of a general wave solution in spherical symmetry.  The $1/r$ factor is there because whoever is writing this down is probably going to take some sort of [radiation zone approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) down the line, and so they're explicitly factoring out the factor so that it will make the final expression for $f$ simpler.  But there is nothing stopping someone from doing some sort of redefinition of $F(r, t) = \frac{f(r,t)}{r}$, and solving for $F$ instead of $f$, at the end of the day.